# Infinite loop breadth first search

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I have tried to implement breadth first search but I believe I get stuck in a infinite for loop and I am not sure why. My method is below:

```
public ArrayList<T> performBreadthFirstSearchUndirectedNonWeighted(UndirectedNonWeightedGraph<T> graph, T startingVertex){

    if (!graph.containsVertex(startingVertex)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vertex doesn't exist.");
    }
    T currentVertex;
    ArrayList<T> traversalOrder = new ArrayList<T>();
    ArrayList<T> visitedVertices = new ArrayList<T>();
    LinkedList<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>(); 

     visitedVertices.add(startingVertex);
     queue.add(startingVertex);

     while (queue.size() != 0) {
         currentVertex = queue.poll();
         traversalOrder.add(currentVertex);

         Iterator<Vertex<T>> i = graph.getNeighbours(currentVertex).iterator(); 

         while (i.hasNext()) { 
             Vertex<T> n = i.next(); 
                if (!visitedVertices.contains(graph.returnVertex(n.getElement()))) { 
                    visitedVertices.add(n.getElement());
                    queue.add(n.getElement()); 
                } 
            } 
     }
    return traversalOrder;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

EDIT: Updated code still infinite loop.

Comment: What does the method `graph.returnVertex()` do?

Comment: Hi @rustyx nice find on the queue.add() line i didnt see that, however it seems to be in a infinite loop still. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: @Ricola it takes a element and returns a Vertex object with that element.

Comment: You call `contains` with `graph.returnVertex(n.getElement())` but add `n.getElement()`. You have to add the same objects for which you do the `contains` check.

Comment: By the way, I think a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) could help you there

Comment: @Ricola ahhh got it thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the line

```
if (!visitedVertices.contains(graph.returnVertex(n.getElement())))
```

by

```
if (!visitedVertices.contains(n.getElement()))
```

The method `contains` accept an `Object` as a parameter so it compiles fine but you have to give a object of type `T`. Normally if you are using an IDE, it should warn you on this line.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of Node `T`  here? Does it implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` properly? Because the key checking of containing elements in the list will fail otherwise. Therefore, will always keep adding nodes to the `Queue`. You can do some simple debugging if the Queue is getting updated as expected.